# How to focus side panel programmatically in google extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to switch focus between "side panel" and the "content(besides side panel)" with keyboard shortcut in google extension. But it didn't work.

[This is the repository](https://github.com/WeiliZheng2022/focus-side-panel-with-keyboard-shortcut)

```json
{
  "permissions": ["sidePanel", "tabs"],
  "commands": {
    "focus-side-panel": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
      },
      "description": "Focus side panel"
    },
    "focus-the-content": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Z",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+Z"
      },
      "description": "Focus the content"
    }
  }
}
```

```js
//side panel javascript
function focusInput(){
  document.getElementById('focus-input').focus()
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message)=>{
  if(message.type==='focusSidePanel'){
    window.focus()
    focusInput()
  }
})
```

```js
//background
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(async (command, tab) => {
  if (command === "focus-side-panel") {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: 'focusSidePanel'
    })
  }
  if (command === "focus-the-content") {
    await chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
    await chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true });
  }
});
```

Comment: There's no such API.